# How to handle disable button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

In my script below code when `Thread.sleep()` is not used, then it throws an exception `"element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-yyo-c131="" class="btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3">...</button> is not clickable at point (226, 567)`.

When using the `Thread.sleep()` it runs and clicks on the Next button, but the problem is that in my application total 9 times next button should be clicked.

For that I printed message on the log so here only 6 times message gets printed ('btn50-400clicked') and then next button is disabled and unable to proceed to next code.

Even after waiting for up to 30 minutes it's not working.

How do I resolve it?

```
var next=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]"))

while(next.isEnabled())
            {
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(9000);
                //var wait15=new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20000)
//wait15.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]")))
                var wait9 =new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 9000)
                wait9.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]"))).click()
                //next.click();
                WDS.log.info('btn50-400clicked')
                
            }
            WDS.log.info('btn2clicked')
            //java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);
            if(!next.isEnabled()){
                           WDS.log.info('Next button disabled')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where you're updating the value of the `next` variable so my expectation is that at some point when the button is disabled the loop is still running.

So my expectation is that you need to change this line:

```
wait9.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]"))).click()
```

to these:

```
next = wait9.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-light border ml-3')]")))
next.click()
```

Also you can try taking screenshots and capturing the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) in case of failure, this way you will get the full picture regarding what went wrong, i.e. put your code into a [try block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) like:

```
var exception = null

try {
    //your code here
} catch (err) {
    WDS.log.error(err.message)
    WDS.log.error('Page source: ' + WDS.browser.getPageSource())
    var screenshot = WDS.browser.getScreenshotAs(pkg.OutputType.FILE)
    screenshot.renameTo(new java.io.File('screenshot.png'))
    exception = err
} finally {
    throw (exception)
}
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)